# How to "unstick" Firefox from a space?

Tags: macos, catalina, spaces, firefox

Whenever I try to open Firefox, it shows up rapidly on the current space but then disappears to move to the space where it has been closed the last time I used it.

For example : I have 3 spaces.
I am on space 2 with Firefox open, I close it.
I go back on space 1, open Firefox -> it will open on space 1 and then immediately the window will disappear to appear in the space 2.
If I move Firefox to space 3, and close it (CMD+Q), the next time I'll launch it, the window will appear in space 3 no matter from which space I launch it.

Not my native language I hope I've been clear enough sorry.

And of course, when I right click Firefox on the dock, under Options, the value of "Assigned To" is "None". (already tried to assign it to a space then go back to none but it doesn't work).

This behaviour only concerns Firefox. All others apps behave like it should : open in the space I'm in.. If you have any idea..

My current macOS version is : macOS Catalina 10.15.4
Firefox version is : 75.0

From comments - Mission Control screenshot

[image]

Comment: 1. Are you using fullscreen? 2. Take a picture of  System Prefs> Mission Control so we can see what you have set.

Comment: 1. Nope not in full screen. 2. here's the link to the screenshot https://ibb.co/x1CbzDM

Comment: OK, thanks. I've inlined it so others can more easily see it. It's not what I was thinking could be the issue, so I'm afraid I'm out of ideas, sorry. Wish you luck.